# Why won't my pictures load on this signature html

Tags: html, outlook

```
<html>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="643" style="width:17.0cm;border-collapse:collapse">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:61.7pt">
                <td width="191" style="width:143.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:61.7pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                        <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Gotham Light&quot;;color:#002060">Maria Laura Quirós<u></u><u></u>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                        <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Gotham Light&quot;;color:#002060">Directora & Socia Door Training and Consulting Costa Rica<u></u><u></u></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                        <span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Gotham Light&quot;;color:#002060">T</span>
                        <span style="font-size:12.0pt;color:#002060"> </span>
                        <span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Gotham Light&quot;;color:#002060">+506 4030 1649<u></u><u></u></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                        <span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Gotham Light&quot;;color:#002060">M +506 6043 5752<u></u><u></u></span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                        <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt">
                            <a href="mailto:m.trescale@www.doorconsultingcr.com" target="_blank">
                                <span lang="DE" style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Gotham Light&quot;;color:blue">marialaura.quiros@doortraining.cr</span>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                        <span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Gotham Light&quot;;color:#002060"><u></u><u></u>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="86" style="width:64.8pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:61.7pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center">
                        <a href="https://www.doorconsultingcr.com/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.doorconsultingcr.com/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709853941252000&amp;usg=AOvVaw1E3AGDFC_gSZJCB0E1PIks">
                            <span lang="EN-US" style="color:windowtext;text-decoration:none">
                                <img border="0" width="71" height="71" style="width:.7395in;height:.7395in" id="m_2269416675111168282Picture_x0020_600157449" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&amp;ik=1ebfc63c3f&amp;attid=0.2&amp;permmsgid=msg-f:1792799726534911592&amp;th=18e14dda4587e668&amp;view=fimg&amp;fur=ip&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ_QzdP_BA8rRCFWZkvoA---jaePk6Jy6Q9ERJbz9yDJSfb0DWK40Nqrp6ok1GJvQ4iEeRbX2YTIurS1XFFILnqQgvigSbPJwcxuQggLV8orc-GFi2cITOBkY_E&amp;disp=emb" alt="A logo with text and confetti
                                
                                Description automatically generated" data-image-whitelisted="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit">
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt"><u></u><u></u></span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="36" style="width:27.3pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:61.7pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="margin-top:1.5pt;text-align:center;line-height:150%">
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/door-training-and-consulting-costa-rica/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.linkedin.com/company/door-training-and-consulting-costa-rica/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709853941252000&amp;usg=AOvVaw3-_OjgEpRhwBWJ8L8PO4tQ">
                            <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt;line-height:150%;color:windowtext;text-decoration:none">
                                <img border="0" width="22" height="22" style="width:.2291in;height:.2291in" id="m_2269416675111168282Picture_x0020_525036754" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&amp;ik=1ebfc63c3f&amp;attid=0.3&amp;permmsgid=msg-f:1792799726534911592&amp;th=18e14dda4587e668&amp;view=fimg&amp;fur=ip&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ_kBLBVrRwT_TEYLnjZaPsXq5uo4Ayqf_PqqoNIZZAKNWVdFpkKChq46C7WCuNgVC1QVCPF0gayJtRB-Yc19ryZYPQiiSj7TCAvYaQliox2v9Z4sjtUdH1WEgA&amp;disp=emb" alt="A pink and black logo

                                Description automatically generated" data-image-whitelisted="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" jslog="32272; 1:WyIjdGhyZWFkLWY6MTc5Mjc5OTcyNjUzNDkxMTU5MiJd; 4:WyIjbXNnLWY6MTc5Mjc5OTcyNjUzNDkxMTU5MiJd">
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt;line-height:150%"><u></u><u></u>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="margin-top:1.5pt;text-align:center;line-height:150%">
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/doortraining.cr" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.instagram.com/doortraining.cr&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709853941252000&amp;usg=AOvVaw06wuOIR7yGlqHGUzaQSzGt">
                            <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt;line-height:150%;color:windowtext;text-decoration:none">
                                <img border="0" width="22" height="22" style="width:.2291in;height:.2291in" id="m_2269416675111168282Picture_x0020_457716067" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&amp;ik=1ebfc63c3f&amp;attid=0.4&amp;permmsgid=msg-f:1792799726534911592&amp;th=18e14dda4587e668&amp;view=fimg&amp;fur=ip&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ_Q9ir3aazBvAhZiEmr-fbVxxuoxCLRluqK8Pl-tM1EovWCQz8HzzQprz4T-voTy0NAM77oysvewVnl0E7ZfowVZicO0eb2GqDH5l61sh6bjQNk7IERWvxpVl4&amp;disp=emb" alt="A logo of a camera

                                Description automatically generated" data-image-whitelisted="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit">
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt;line-height:150%"><u></u><u></u>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:6.0pt;margin-left:0cm;text-align:center;line-height:150%">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/doorconsultingcr" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/doorconsultingcr&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709853941253000&amp;usg=AOvVaw0P1DLkg5lfgbTGWA6z5wnQ">
                            <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt;line-height:150%;color:windowtext;text-decoration:none">
                                <img border="0" width="22" height="22" style="width:.2291in;height:.2291in" id="m_2269416675111168282Picture_x0020_129888742" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&amp;ik=1ebfc63c3f&amp;attid=0.5&amp;permmsgid=msg-f:1792799726534911592&amp;th=18e14dda4587e668&amp;view=fimg&amp;fur=ip&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ9obUW0PsGgtFTd3p73qGSjfGiEG_Acucq7nF9FoGDZSMEnX0HwW0Dk-WlBR4y7TuiJftOcTV8yMI_iJCGXagFMid66fisnoUk_mQRF75VGvnQ7qzCRHHHLz84&amp;disp=emb" alt="A black and pink logo
                                
                                Description automatically generated" data-image-whitelisted="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit">
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt;line-height:150%"><u></u><u></u>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="263" style="width:197.25pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:61.7pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                        <a href="https://www.doorconsultingcr.com/leadership-architecture" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.doorconsultingcr.com/leadership-architecture&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709853941253000&amp;usg=AOvVaw24D1u9F7hbxiMODd5GO7--">
                            <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt;color:windowtext;text-decoration:none">
                                <img border="0" width="248" height="76" style="width:2.5833in;height:.7916in" id="m_2269416675111168282Picture_x0020_943383402" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&amp;ik=1ebfc63c3f&amp;attid=0.6&amp;permmsgid=msg-f:1792799726534911592&amp;th=18e14dda4587e668&amp;view=fimg&amp;fur=ip&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ_O60ATPym9axyj0ld_J88NFazs9UrzUlumxdwJFE2HKWJ6kkMC7dO06xmBBO2G9mn2oR8_TQVsjzublsF3BKTXceBRTJHrLoxB1AQgvr7-gDPkB0GkhZzL16k&amp;disp=emb" alt="A black background with blue text
                                
                                Description automatically generated" data-image-whitelisted="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit">
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt"><u></u><u></u>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="66" style="width:49.6pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:61.7pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal">
                        <a href="https://www.doorconsultingcr.com/leadership-architecture" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.doorconsultingcr.com/leadership-architecture&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1709853941253000&amp;usg=AOvVaw24D1u9F7hbxiMODd5GO7--">
                            <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt;color:windowtext;text-decoration:none">
                                <img border="0" width="73" height="73" style="width:.7604in;height:.7604in" id="m_2269416675111168282Picture_x0020_732619802" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&amp;ik=1ebfc63c3f&amp;attid=0.7&amp;permmsgid=msg-f:1792799726534911592&amp;th=18e14dda4587e668&amp;view=fimg&amp;fur=ip&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ-29FMgjYqItFD990VR0dUPNPfR8aKheoOykHsx4CJ83A3PATA3PeDPRa2NQiMXewpmOmrH6w9OB3y0gy9qNBKcZcDcaf0AAH0iKGjvHDQT0UFuxliCkrHRIL4&amp;disp=emb" alt="A white background with black and white clouds
                                Description automatically generated" data-image-whitelisted="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit">
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:8.0pt"><u></u><u></u>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

I've made this HTML file on VS to make a signature for outlook. The issue is that the pictures won't load from the sender's nor the receiver's end. When I open the HTML file on my computer the pictures are there. Not sure if I'm missing something or if I'm completely off, but any pointers would be apriciated

Receiver POV (I did try to click on load pictures but it stayed the same)

[image: Receiver POV]

Sender POV (I did try to click on load pictures but it stayed the same)

[image: Sender POV]

How it's supposed to look like

[image: How it's supposed to look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image sources you're using seem to point to attachment images within an email you received in gmail: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&amp;ik=1ebfc63c3f&amp;attid=0.7&amp;permmsgid=msg-f:1792799726534911592&amp;th=18e14dda4587e668&amp;view=fimg&amp;fur=ip&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ-29FMgjYqItFD990VR0dUPNPfR8aKheoOykHsx4CJ83A3PATA3PeDPRa2NQiMXewpmOmrH6w9OB3y0gy9qNBKcZcDcaf0AAH0iKGjvHDQT0UFuxliCkrHRIL4&amp;disp=emb`

You can only view those if you're logged into Gmail in your browser. Neither your email client, nor any other email client, will have a login cookie for your gmail inbox, which is why it won't work in any email. It does work if you save it as HTML file and view it in your browser, as you're logged into your gmail account there.

To solve this, you need to host the images somewhere where they're publicly availabe, embedd them into your email using MIME Multipart Mail or embed them inside your html using data-urls and base64 encoding.

Comment: Hey there! Sorry for the late reply! Solved the issue, kind of a dumb mistake. Thanks a lot!